# Can I use Paypal APIs for sending money from one user to another directly?

Tags: paypal, payment, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am developing an app that can transfer payments between users using their phones. Need to use a third party payment service that enables sending money using either phone number or email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Paypal's Adaptive payment api [check this out.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/)
Moreover paypal has features of implicit payment where api user and sender will be same and with your code (with the help of api secret and password) you can send payment from one paypal to other paypal account or card.